# How to dissociate a vlan from Vyatta Router?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am able to associate using `SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan::createObject`,
but while disassociating getting error. For disassociation I am using `SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan::deleteObject`.

Seems issue with 
Headers
Required Headers:

```
SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_VlanInitParameters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you associate a VLAN with the createObject it returns the ID of the new associated vlan, you need that ID for the deleteObject method that is the  SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_VlanInitParameters.

A RestFul request would be like this:

```
https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/$ID/deleteObject.json

Note: replace $USER, $APIKEY and $ID
```